# testing code on ie6 without installing it?

Tags: html, windows, browser, internet-explorer-6

I'm on windows 7. Is there any way I could test the IE6-tuned code on my local machine without installing the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx).

Comment: is it free? do i need Microsoft Expression Web for that to run?

Comment: Yes, Expression Web 3 SuperPreview for Internet Explorer is free

Answer (score 1):

[Spoon.net](http://www.spoon.net/) offers a pile of hosted applications including all kinds of [browsers](http://www.spoon.net/Browsers/) without local installation.  [IE6](http://www.spoon.net/IE6), [IE7](http://www.spoon.net/IE7), [IE8](http://www.spoon.net/IE8), are just a few of them. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

http://spoon.net/browsers/

Let's you test IE6 and all other browsers, even if the site is still on your local workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Try Adobe's BrowserLab.  It runs in your browser and can emulate IE 6.  You'll just need to register for free with Adobe.

http://browserlab.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

[This is a popular site](http://browsershots.org/) that can render pages in a number of different browsers, including IE6. There are other sites too.

You can also install [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) (free from Microsoft for Windows 7 Pro, Enterprise, and Ultimate users only), to run a Windows XP virtual machine, and thereby IE6, which comes preinstalled.

Comment: that is such a pain. isn't their any way i could do it locally?

Comment: @Ibrahim: not sure if you saw my update with the XP Mode - that's local. But I'm pretty sure there's no way to run IE6 natively on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

Comment: that is what i was downloading.. :), i googled and got to know about it.

Comment: just be aware it doesn't handle popups very well.

Comment: @scunlife i do not use pop up at all. BTW thanks for adding the information.